# Adding Error Messages to Dynamic Fields in React Hook Form

Tags: typescript, forms, validation, react-hooks

I'm unable to get error messages from React Hook Form when using Dynamic Fields (works for non-dynamic) in typescript, likely a syntax error

`errors.userInput[index].type?.message` is giving me an `errors.userInput` is possibly undefined error.
 I've tried all kinds of syntax possibilities for this line but I'm not clear on what is causing this issue.

Here's my code

```
const form = useForm<FormData>({
    defaultValues: {
      userInput: [
        {
          type: "",
          category: "",
          subcategory: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  });

const { register, handleSubmit, control, formState } = form;
const { errors } = formState;

const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    name: "userInput",
    control,
  });

return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
    <div>
       {fields.map((field, index) => {
       return (
          <div key={field.id}>
           <label>Add income or an expense?</label>
              <select
                  defaultValue=""
                  {...register(`userInput.${index}.type` as const, {
                  required: { value: true, message: "Field is required" },
                  })}
                  >
                    <option value="expense">Expense</option>
                    <option value="income">Income</option>
                    <option value="liability">Liability</option>
                  </select>
                  <p className="error">{errors.userInput[index].type?.message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    </div>
  );
```

I'm basing this from examples I've seen for using error messages on non-dynamic fields that look like this and seem to work fine:

```
<select
       defaultValue=""
       {...register("type", {
        required: { value: true, message: "Field is required" },
        })}
        >
       <option value="expense">Expense</option>
       <option value="income">Income</option>
       <option value="liability">Liability</option>
       </select>
      <p className="error">{errors.type?.message}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
errors.userInput[index].type?.message
```

Here with this syntax you are checking if `errors.userInput[index].type` is defined but you are not sure if `errors.userInput` is.

however

> `errors.userInput` is possibly undefined

makes sense, therefore you need to use the optional chaining `?.` for each level

```js
errors?.userInput?.[index]?.type?.message
```

[code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBEBcMCGYCeMC8MA3gFAwwCuEiAkmAA4VRpnkwDarbRUO9caIgFs4ECJgDmAmAHJMMgL4KANF3I8+A4aPFSMMgEaKVa4r36CRYydJnBjagLokFAbhKhIsRMlQAmDGw8QgowABM4ADMASzA4MPdPaBhYiIAPAhgARhIPcAgQABs4ADpCkAkACh8UCAB+EqpaBiYG9lS4NMcG8zgGq104AEoYAHpRmDAQeCQUPMgi0vKqmv8GpoQ6Rig2jq6ezX6dGxHxyenVoA)

Comment: That got me halfway there! Looks like there was also a conflict with naming the field "type", changed to "incometype" and everything looks good. Thank you!

Comment: @rasputinsgoat yes, avoid using reserved keywords! ^^